# Batch size and epoch for LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

I am trying to learn LSTM that is applied to sequential data.

I am referring to following study material available here: https://its-ml.de/index.php/plattscaling/

Its given that:

sequence_length = 50

batch_size = 200

epochs = 100

nb_features = 25

Can somebody please let me know what does Batch size and epoch signifies here.

Comment: Check the linked threads.